# Why can't the old Mongoose Models have the newly added fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am a self-taught MERN stack developer and still learning. I have been trying to see how this is done in real production. Take for instance, I have a User Model in my MongoDB database like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    })
```

And users created account and they are stored and they are about 10 users already. I have written my logics for this in nodejs. And in the future, I decided to add another field to the User model to enable me to write additional logics for this model in nodejs. Take for instance, I decided to add password field.

```
 const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    })
```

It is obvious that the previous 10 users won't have the new password field in their own models in MongoDB. Any new user who creates account after the field is added will surely be stored with the new password field.
How do I make the new password field to be added to the previous 10 users? What if I have logics that may depend on this password field for all users going forward? How do they handle such in production?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your users are logging in without 'passwords' but in production, You can do two things:

1. Send link to old users with 'password change request URL -> so they can set it on their own.
2. Generate a temporary password and send it to them by email. And in the first login attempt, they will have to change it to their own.
3. You can send an email to those 10 users with information, that they have to click on the button 'Remember password'

It all depends on your website policy.

But in case of setting other fields as required, you should go with some migration or default field value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was just an example. The use case was more of a field. We were building an API and we needed a logic to handle a complex stuff and we decided to introduce a new field inside the User Model that is Boolean value. Though this API is not yet live. But I started thinking about it if this was already live and users are already registered. I decided to ask the question. You mentioned migration. Could you explain more about this?

Comment: Migrations are special 'scripts' for updating your data/data structure. They are for keeping your data/data structure in every environment. So for example initially your migration version is 1.0.0. At that moment your field 'fieldA' is a field that holds only one value. But then in the future, you might need to transform that field into an array of values. So the solution for that kind of 'schema changes' is to write migration which will transform value of fieldA for every object in given model, to contain singleElement array  (with the previous value of that field).

Comment: after that it will fit current schema state, there are some plugins for mongoose like https://github.com/balmasi/migrate-mongoose. In my company we use this one -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-migrate-ts